# Creating a d3.js scale with svg elements as range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a scale which contains the svg elements as range. E.g. a linear continous scale with a range containing circles with radius ranging from 0 to 100 and which can also be queried for those circles. The purpose of this is to pass the scale to a legend maker which uses the nice properties of d3 scales to construct a legend.

I am able to create circles that I see in the browser's page inspector but they are not displayed where it matters. Why is that? If append() accepts a dom element why isn't it displayed?

```
let canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 200);

let domFun = function(scale, range) {
    scale.range(range);
    return function(d) {
        let template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = scale(d);
        let dom = template.content.childNodes[0];
        return dom;
    }
};

let cScale = domFun(d3.scaleLinear(), ["<circle r = 0>", "<circle r = 100>"]);

let data = [0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 1];

canvas.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
    .append(d => cScale(d))
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => (i + 0.5) * 200)
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

Grateful for any help/input here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answer is the typical D3 approach to this sort of task, you can make this work with one modification.

You need to specify an SVG namespace when creating the elements. This might look like:

```
    return function(d) {
        let template = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, "svg")
        template.innerHTML = scale(d);
        let dom = template.firstChild;
        return dom;
    }
```

Altogether that looks something like:

```js
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 200);

let domFun = function(scale, range) {
    scale.range(range);
    return function(d) {
        let template = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, "svg")
        template.innerHTML = scale(d);
        let dom = template.firstChild;
        return dom;
    }
};

let cScale = domFun(d3.scaleLinear(), ["<circle r = 0>", "<circle r = 100>"]);

let data = [0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 1];

svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
    .append(d => cScale(d))
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => (i + 0.5) * 200)
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use the scale to construct some tags and use a function to extract it from inside another tag?

Just use the scale to calculate the radius and the circles are visible

```
let canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 200);

let cScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 100]);
let data = [0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 1];

canvas.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d => cScale(d))
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => (i + 0.5) * 200)
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

**Edit**

Instead of using the string interpolator and constructing a DOM element it can be done with the Object interpolator. This allows you to also interpolate colors.

```
let canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 200);

let icScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([{r:10, fill:"red", cx:100}, {r:100, fill:"yellow", cx:700, cy:100, shape:"circle"}]);
let data = icScale.ticks(5);

let shape = icScale(data[0]).shape;
canvas.selectAll(shape).data(data).enter()
    .append(shape)
    .attrs(d => icScale(d));
```

you need to add

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

this to your HTML page to use the `.attrs()`.

Only the second object needs to have the `shape` attribute, and also because here `cy` does not change, it only needs to be in the second object.

If you need to keep the object returned by the scale be aware that you have to **make a copy**.

Comment: Thanks for the input! My (possibly misguided) idea is to create a function which constructs legends (as in an explanatory color/size/orientation/symbol/pattern guide next to the graph). Therefore I need to have the objects themselves contained in the scale so that I can make easy use of the ticks() function to create both svg object and data value. Hope that makes sense. Andrew Reid's answer really helped me on the way.